# How to query oData for tag badge

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, badges, data-explorer

Could you please hint me how to query [oData](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) properly to determine how soon will I get a tag badge - "Earned 100 upvotes for answers in the [some] tag."

i.e. total sum of all upvotes to my posts grouped by tag, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one query which shows you the amount of badge-eligible upvotes for each tag:
[How many upvotes do I have for each tag?](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1928). You might want to change `TOP 20` to control the amount of returned rows. There's right now unfortunately a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63692/a-couple-of-popular-queries-on-the-data-explorer-arent-working) manifesting which causes wrong query results. Have a bit of patience until Waffles get it fixed.

#### See also

- [Interesting queries on Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer)

Comment: Indeed, that query returns absolute wrong result - 5 tags with 1 vote meanwhile I got already the C# badge

Comment: @Nick: you didn't notice the [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63692/a-couple-of-popular-queries-on-the-data-explorer-arent-working) link in my answer? :)

Comment: I ummmm, new glasses a few days ago, still adjusting?