# OData.Stackexchange.Com does not function for Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A couple of (popular) queries on the Data Explorer aren't working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63692/a-couple-of-popular-queries-on-the-data-explorer-arent-working)

http://odata.stackexchange.com/ <-- Note that the numbers for stack overflow read zero.

Comment: Yet it does function... Try running a query.

Comment: @Peter: I tried http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag and the result is an empty set.

Comment: @Billy - Strange. For me too, yet the others seem to work. For example [this one](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/96/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate) and [this one](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/87/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site) work for me.

Comment: This is a duplicate question (sort of)  see this question for details http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63692/a-couple-of-popular-queries-on-the-data-explorer-arent-working

Comment: And some of the other ones don't seem to work either, like [the Jon Skeet comparison](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/143/jon-skeet-comparison)

Comment: @Barry: Yes, it's a duplicate -- feel free to close as such. Couldn't seem to find that question though :( (I did search for quite some time.. :sigh:)

Comment: @Billy ONeal - I'd love to be able to do such tasks but I am a just a mere mortal on MSO.  Have flagged for mod attention.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Thank you very much :)