# What is the story with SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The SEDE looks sad.  Stack Overflow is missing data it appears.

[image: sede is sad]

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63692/a-couple-of-popular-queries-on-the-data-explorer-arent-working) for more info.

Comment: I would say that this is definitely not a dupe of that question.  Waffles answer answers it, but the question is not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed now.

I added retry logic which made the importer go through, this should not be a problem again next month.

Comment: Hm, the generalist queries don't work yet: [#1](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag), [#2](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/299/how-long-until-i-get-the-generalist-badge).

Comment: Georg Working on it ...

Answer (score 1):

[An answer from Waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63692/a-couple-of-popular-queries-on-the-data-explorer-arent-working/63722#63722) on another question explains it:

> I have attempted once, twice or thrice four times to upload the Data and SQL Azure just shuts the connection on me after loading up a few million votes.
>
> I will fix SO slow tomorrow so it has a more graceful way of restarting / resuming the process.
>
> It should be online again in the next day or so.